# mod rewrite, transform urls for old app to new app

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a mod rewrite issue to resolve, I am by no means an expert.  I believe I am getting close but not quite there.

I have an old app, where the doc root for the app was located at 
http://doma.in/PlantImages/, and particular pages were loaded using 
http://doma.in/PlantImages/ImageData.asp?IDN=01-002h or similar.  I need mod rewrite to access the new app using 
http://doma.in/index.php?mod=media&func=view&ot=collection&tpl=tree and individual pages using http://doma.in/index.php?mod=media&func=display&ot=medium&slug=01-002h

What's more, the new app has an existing set of rewrite rules for handling short URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

What I currently have is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^IDN=$1
RewriteRule ^/PlantImages/ImageData\.asp index.php?mod=media&func=display&ot=medium&slug=$1

RewriteRule ^PlantImages/ index.php?mod=media&func=view&ot=collection&tpl=tree

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I do have this close to working, but not quite.  When the first condition and rule are commented out, the 2nd (PlantImages/) properly redirects.  But when not commented out the first one doesn't redirect at all, css is broken, and the 2nd one is broken too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a capture group in your query string match, not a backreference:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^IDN=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/PlantImages/ImageData\.asp index.php?mod=media&func=display&ot=medium&slug=%1
```

And then backreference the grouping with `%1` instead of `$1`.

Then you need to use a `$` in your second rule's pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^PlantImages/$ index.php?mod=media&func=view&ot=collection&tpl=tree
```

Comment: Still not working.  The first rule causes the page to load as if it can't find the page, and the 2nd shows no difference from before.  Looking at the rewritelog, it appears that relative URIs to style sheets are being prepended with "PlantImages".